# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' in python nltk

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I have this code:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
import re

fo = open('cran.all.1400', 'r+')
contents = fo.read()
docs = re.split(r'\.I[\s][\d]*')

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))

tokens = []
for each in docs:
    tokens.append(word_tokenize(eac))

s_words = [w for w in tokens if not w in stop_words]
print(s_words)
```

When I try to run it, I get this error:

[image: error]

how can I solve this?

Comment: Please, don't post text (code and error messages) as images. It makes it difficult to help you

Comment: The elements of `tokens`, which you are calling `each` are apparently lists and since `stop_words` is a set, they must be (but lists are not) hashable.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your variable `each` is a list, and you try to look if the latter belongs to a `set`. The `in` operator needs that `each` is hashable in order to search for it in the set.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's related, but I'm thinking you mean `[w for w in tokens if w not in stop_words]`

`tokens.append(word_tokenize(each))` <-- that is likely giving you a 2d array.  So `each` is a list.  Perhaps you're expecting this to be a 1 dimensional list, in which case you could use `tokens.concat(word_tokenize(each))`